# Creating extra columns based on condition (Case When Sum)

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, sum, case

I have survey table where someone is asked roughly 5 questions. 4 of those questions are the same questions, but the options to their answers are different since they were to understand their purchase.

Here are the questions:

```
 ID                Question                            qid                         Answer
 101005 what brands did you purchase the past 5 months  1          Coca-Cola or Pepsi or Dr.Pepper
 101005 what brands did you purchase the past 5 months  1                       Dr.Pepper
 101005 what brands did you purchase the past 5 months  1                      store brand
 101005 what brands did you purchase the past 5 months  1                      Coca-Cola
 101005  how many people live in your house             4                           4
 101005  what is your prefer retailers                  8                          walmart
```

The goal is to create four extra columns based on their answer and they will be assigned a 1 or 0. Since this person's answer is coca cola, I want to assign them in the column of current_buyer and give them 1 and 0 will be new_buyer column. I also want to make sure that even though he answer Dr.Pepper in the second row, it still recognizes him as a current_buyer. In the same breath I want to assign this person a 1 in the 3rd column as a drinker and 0 4th column in prospect.

Here is how the table should look like

```
  ID             Question                             qid               answer                    Current_buyer    New_buyer   drinker    prospect      
 101005 what brands did you purchase the past 5 months  1        Coca-Cola or Pepsi or Dr.Pepper      1               0             1        0
 101005 what brands did you purchase the past 5 months  1                       Dr.Pepper             1               0             1        0
 101005 how many people live in your house              4                            4                1               0             1        0
```

The goal is to see if ID bought coca-cola the past 5 months, they are a current buyer (1) and drinker (1) and  will have (0) for new_buyer and prospect in their entire profile.

Here is the code that I try:

```
 select ID,qid,question,answer,s_date,   
 Case when Sum(Case when [answer] like'%coca-cola%' then 1 else 0 end)>=1 then 1 
 else 0 end  current_buyer
 ,Case when Sum(Case when [answer] like'%coca-cola%' then 1 else 0 end)=0 then 1 
  else 0 end  New_buyer 
 ,Case when Sum(Case when [answer] like'%coca-cola,Dr.pepper,pepsi%' then 1 else 0 end)>=1 then 1 
  else 0 end  drinker
 ,Case when Sum(Case when [answer] like'%coca-cola,Dr.pepper,pepsi%' then 1 else 0 end)=0 then 1 
  else 0 end  Prospect
```

Unfortunately, using this code I'm getting 0 in the drinker column even though people selected coca-cola. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure that I understand the logic behind assigning the various values, but in general it seems that you are assigning the value based on an aggregation of multiple rows. Therefore you need to do the aggregation first (in this case in a CTE) and then join back to that for your query.

Also worth noting is that even though your are doing your matching with a LIKE operator - everything between the [%] characters will need to match exactly somewhere in your [answer]. I don't think that this is what you want - so I've split them out. However I'm not 100% sure if I've got the logical operators completely correct.

Do you need something like:

```
;with analysisCTE as (select ID,qid,   
     Case when Sum(Case when [answer] like'%coca-cola%' then 1 else 0 end)>=1 then 1 
     else 0 end  current_buyer
     ,Case when Sum(Case when [answer] like'%coca-cola%' then 1 else 0 end)=0 then 1 
      else 0 end  New_buyer 
     ,Case when Sum(Case when [answer] like'%coca-cola%' OR [answer] like '%Dr.pepper%' OR [answer] like '%pepsi%' then 1 else 0 end)>=1 then 1 
      else 0 end  drinker
     ,Case when Sum(Case when [answer] like'%coca-cola%' OR [answer] like '%Dr.pepper%' OR [answer] like '%pepsi%' then 1 else 0 end)=0 then 1 
      else 0 end  Prospect
    from drinks
    group by id, qid)
select d.ID,d.qid,d.question,d.answer, a.current_buyer, a.New_buyer, a.drinker, a.Prospect
from drinks d
inner join analysisCTE a on d.id = a.id and d.qid = a.qid
```

Comment: unfortunately the query only assign them current buyer, drinker only for the question they answer and for the other question they are seen as new_buyer. I want to assign a person's entire profile as current_buyer and drinker no matter what they answer in if they have selected coca-cola.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm struggling to understand your requirements here - any chance you could post a set of sample data, and what you want your query output to look like?

Comment: I've updated my answer - does this get you closer? (I've called your first table drinks in my test database)

Comment: here is here a fiddle with a sample of the datahttp://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62af4c/3

Comment: Unfortunately the fiddle doesn't seem to support the CTE syntax.